# Onchange triggers on load instead of when the select value changes

Tags: javascript, select, onchange

I made an extract of my code to help explain this: http://jsfiddle.net/DF2Uw/1/

I basically want to see when a user changes the value of slottime. I use a simple onchange handler: `slottime.setAttribute(onchange, alert("oh no"));`

However this seems to trigger as soon as the select gets generated on the page instead of when the value is changed. I don't understand why, this makes no sense to me.

Can anybody explain the logic to me and maybe propose a fix?

Comment: Maybe because you're calling the "event handler" instead of assigning it? alert("oh no") will just pop a window that says "oh no" whenever that line of code is executed, use function () {alert("oh no");} instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use `.addEventListener` instead of setting attribute.
2. You are not actually setting an attribute value. You are invoking a
   function `alert()`. Change it to: `setAttribute('onchange', 'alert("oh no")')`

Fiddle with `.addEventListener`: http://jsfiddle.net/DF2Uw/2/